# android tableLayout column color issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to have a Tablelayout with following properties,

1.I want to change background color of column  . Now if i am setting background for a TextView it is wraping the content and putting that color not the entire column.I want different color for my two columns.
2. change  space between two columns (probably border).
 Anybody have done such thing please help me .                Thanks

```
<TableLayout

    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/NameLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#1DA43F"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/NameText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/NameLabel"
            android:background="@color/DarkRed"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
              </TableRow></TableLayout>
```

Comment: Show us you current code.

Comment: When you say 'I should be able to change' you mean dynamically or in XML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NameText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/DarkRed"
            android:text="@string/NameLabel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />        

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1DA43F"
            android:text="@string/NameLabel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your original code:

- Replace `TableLayout` and `TableRow` with `LinearLayout` (no need for table, you only have one row)
- Add a `android:padding` to your `TextViews` for spaccing
- Remove `android:layout_gravity="right"` and `android:layout_gravity="left"` and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to both `TextViews`

Comment: Hi ,want  different colors for two columns. I think Specifying color at row level will give same color to both column . edited question.

Comment: I have an image which shows what i want but i am unable to upload bcoz it requires some higher reputation..

Comment: thanks but If i have more that one row..will this work....and also i want to align first column text to right and second column text to left...